# Why is my reputation decreased by 1?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I know how reputation works and also read this post [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

According to this post your reputation will be decreased by 1 when *you vote an answer down/not useful*.

As you can see in my profile -1 reputation is deducted from my account even though I didn't downvote on this post. So I'm not sure what it represents.

> [image]

Comment: Did you consider that this is not a single reputation change, but many rolled into one which turned out as -1 for you?

Comment: Click the `view more` link to get specific reasons for every reputation change. This might tell you exactly where this `-1` comes from.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a total of 3 upvotes and 8 downvotes on that question, at this time.

```
3 * 5 = 15
8 * -2 = -16

15 - 16 = -1
```

Comment: You math goood.

Comment: @TimPost - I was very careful not to make any off-by-one errors!

Answer (score 2):

That is reputation summary which shows your last four posts' total reputation (gained-lost). Calculation is already done by @Oded.

To see detailed reputation summary you need to view [your reputation page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/219272/sachin?tab=reputation).